# close a window and do not exit the application

Tags: javafx-8

Good evening everyone, 
I have a test application consists of two windows: Main, Window1. 
to display the "Window1" window from the main window I click on a button. My problem is that closing the "window1" window automatically close the application. I would like when I click on (X) of the window "window1" I have to return to the main window (not exit the application). 
here is the code:

**MainScreen.fxml**

```
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="166.0" prefWidth="307.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="testexample.MainScreenController">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="128.0" layoutY="127.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#showScreen1" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="57.0" text="show..." />
      <Label layoutX="114.0" layoutY="31.0" text="Main Screen">
         <font>
            <Font size="25.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**MainScreenController**

```
public class MainScreenController implements Initializable {

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}

@FXML
private void showScreen1(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    Parent root = (Parent) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Screen1.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}}
```

**Screen1.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="202.0" prefWidth="463.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="testexample.Screen1Controller">
    <children>
        <Label layoutX="58.0" layoutY="40.0" prefHeight="53.0" prefWidth="342.0" text="Welcome to screen 1">
            <font>
                <Font size="36.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

class that contains method start() and method main():

```
public class TestExample extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainScreen.fxml"));
    Scene sc = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(sc);
    stage.show();

}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a JavaFX application will exit when all windows are closed. You can prevent this behavior by calling

```
Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
```

in your `Application`'s `start(...)` method.

I'm not sure this is your problem, however, because nowhere in your code do you create a second window: you just load up a new FXML file, put its contents in a new Scene, and display it in the existing window:

```
@FXML
private void showScreen1(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    // Load new FXML file and save root Node as "root":
    Parent root = (Parent) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Screen1.fxml"));

    // Create a new Scene to display the root node just loaded:
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    // Get a reference to the existing stage (the window containing the source of the event; the "show..." Button)
    Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

    // Set the new scene in the existing stage:
    stage.setScene(scene);

    // Show the existing stage (though it is already showing, I think):
    stage.show();
}
```

From your description, it sounds like you want to create a second window, which the user has to dismiss before returning to the original window. You can do this by creating a new stage, making its owner the existing stage, and making it modal:

```
@FXML
private void showScreen1(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    Parent root = (Parent) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Screen1.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    Window existingWindow = ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

    // create a new stage:
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    // make it modal:
    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    // make its owner the existing window:
    stage.initOwner(existingWindow);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: I edited the post to clarify the problem. I wrote the complete code

Comment: Nowhere in your code do you create a second window, though. I edited the answer; I'm still not quite sure exactly what you are trying to do but maybe that helps.

Comment: this line "stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);" is unnecessary, isn't it?